# How do I programmatically query a DbSet in a DbContext?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am trying to build a controller that services edit requests for all my lookup tables. I have several DbSet variables on my DbContext that derive from `IdNamePairBase`, e.g:

```
public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; } // Country derives from IdNamePairBase
```

How can I pass the name of one of these to a query, to get all items in that list? E.g.

```
var list = db.GetNamedDbSet("Countries");
```

Then, for bonus points I need to get an `IEnumerable<IdNamePairBase>` from `list`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `Set(Type type)` on the DbContext if the name of the table corresponds to the type.

```
 public IEnumerable<IdNamePairBase> GetNamedDbSet(string dbSetName)
 {
      var property = Type.GetType(dbSetName);
      if (property == null || !property.CanRead)
      {
         throw new ArgumentException("DbSet named " + dbSetName + " does not exist." );
      }

      // at this point you might want to check that the property is an enumerable type
      // and that the generic definition is convertible to IdNamePairBase by
      // inspecting the property type.  If you're sure that these hold, you could
      // omit the check.

      return Set(type).Cast<IdNamePairBase>();
 }
```

**Original Answer**

If the name of the set matches the property name, you can use reflection.

```
 public IEnumerable<IdNamePairBase> GetNamedDbSet( string dbSetName )
 {
      var property = this.GetType().GetProperty( dbSetName );
      if (property == null || !property.CanRead)
      {
         throw new ArgumentException("DbSet named " + dbSetName + " does not exist." );
      }

      // at this point you might want to check that the property is an enumerable type
      // and that the generic definition is convertible to IdNamePairBase by
      // inspecting the property type.  If you're sure that these hold, you could
      // omit the check.

      var result = new List<IdNamePairBase>();
      foreach (var item in (IEnumerable)property.GetValue( this, null))
      {
          result.Add( (IdNamePairBase)item );
      }
      return result;
 }
```

Comment: I got the property value from reflection as you indicate, thanks, but I was hoping for a dynamic type cast to the correct DbSet<T> type first. I'll update the question shortly.

Comment: @ProfK - that's trickier than I thought because to get a strongly typed (generic) method to the correct DbSet, you have to know the type.  If you know the type, then you should be able to simply use the appropriate property.  I doubt whether a non-generic DbSet, which could be done easily, would work.

Comment: GetNamedDbSet  is exactly what i need but visual studio can not find IdNamePairBase definition . I am trying to make DbContext extension class for it ! What to do ? Help.

Comment: @Add080bbA use your own class name. The one in this answer was specific to the question.

Comment: What about if none is certain ! Let's say i want the key property collection of a dbset named "employees" or "firms" . I think i did not understand the solution

Comment: @Add080bbA not quite sure what you're asking but you might be able to get that information from the DbContext configuration or, worst case, add a custom attribute to the property (as a marker) so that you could get it via reflection once you have an instance of the class. That is, get the `PropertyInfo`s of the type for the instance, find the one that has the custom attribute on it (or is configured as the Key property), then get the value using the `PropertyInfo.GetValue()` method on your instance.  Or use a convention - i.e., it's always named "Id", instead of a custom attribute.